# 2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

This is my MySQLConnector code.

```
import logging
import pymysql

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MySQLConnector:
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.connection = None
        self._connect(config=config)

    def _connect(self, config):
        config["charset"] = "utf8mb4"
        config["cursorclass"] = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(**config)

    def read(self, query, params=None):
        result = None
        try:
            with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query, params)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
                self.connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
        return result
```

And I use that like this.

```
connector = MySQLConnector(config=config)
while True:
    query = "SELECT * FROM my_table"
    print(connector.read(query=query))
    time.sleep(30)
```

This works well but after few hours later, this process raise error (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'), and I can't find the reason.

Comment: Looks like your connection timed out and the server closed it. It needs to be reestablish.

Comment: @KlausD. Do you mean [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) wait_timeout? But I thought It's irrelevant because I execute a query every 30 secs.

Comment: Only the server will be able to tell you why the connection was seperated. Check the logs, maybe increase the log level.